# Why is `(2 == 2) == True` equal `True` but `2 == 2 == True` is equal `False`?

Tags: python

My problem are these two statements:

```
> 2 == 2 == True
False
> (2 == 2) == True
True
```

I am confused. I expected both expressions to be the same since Python would evaluate the expression from left to right, so:

```py
# 2 == 2 == True
# |    |
# ------
#   |
#  True  == True
```

and

```
# (2 == 2) == True
#  |    |
#  ------
#    |
#   True   == True
```

Even if I change the order (if Python evaluated from right to left), I get the same confusing result:

```
> True == 2 == 2
False
> True == (2 == 2)
True
```

Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Because `2 == 2 == True` is _chained_ to `2 == 2 and 2 == True`.

Comment: The integer value of `True` is 1, which is why you're getting `False`.

Comment: Do not assume == will have the same order of execution as simple mathematical operator +, -, * or /. In this case your second == asks if 2 == True, which results in false.

Comment: @Steven no, `A` and `C` aren't compared.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) might help.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I didn't know about this special behaviour in Python. I didn't find the other post during my research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Comparison chaining.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) `2 == 2 == True` is evaluated as `2 == 2 and 2 == True`, and the second comparison is clearly false. (`2` may be *truthy*, but it is not `True`.)

You can use the `ast` module to see the different abstract syntax trees (ASTs) produced from each expression.

```
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("2 == 2 == True").body[0], indent=2))
Expr(
  value=Compare(
    left=Constant(value=2),
    ops=[
      Eq(),
      Eq()],
    comparators=[
      Constant(value=2),
      Constant(value=True)]))

>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("(2 == 2) == True").body[0], indent=2))
Expr(
  value=Compare(
    left=Compare(
      left=Constant(value=2),
      ops=[
        Eq()],
      comparators=[
        Constant(value=2)]),
    ops=[
      Eq()],
    comparators=[
      Constant(value=True)]))
```

---

Looking at the AST alone doesn't make it obvious that `A op1 B op2 C` is equivalent to `A op1 B and B op2 C` (You can see that there is a *single* `Compare` expression with two operators and two "comparators", rather than a `Compare` expression with a single operator and another `Compare` expression as one operand.) For that, you need the documentation:

> Formally, if `a`, `b`, `c`, …, `y`, `z` are expressions and `op1`, `op2`, …, `opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

The AST provides the information, the code generator provides the semantics of that information.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('2==2==True')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
             14 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('(2==2)==True')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```